# could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies strong name validation failed

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting

> could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies strong name validation failed

I created sample project(windows Application using C#) and added one Class-library project(**ClassLibrary1**).

Created one strong name public key and added to both the projects using **signing option with delay signing** checked.

able to build the solution but, not able to run the project. getting above error message.
need to do anything else.